# iOS Swift 5 Deeplink userActivity Method not called

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

In Swift 4 it's working fine in all device and iOS versions.

After upgrading to swift 5 deeplink open the app, But userActivity method is not called.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL
        else { return false }
        print(url)
        return true
    }
```

Our App support iOS 10 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`restorationHandler` Callback type has been changed from `[Any]` to `[UIUserActivityRestoring]` then it's working fine for me.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL
        else { return false }
        print(url)
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you set the initial viewController via **SceneDelegate**. You need to add this to **SceneDelegate**

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
              let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
                  return
              }
        print(url)
    }
```